# swapping 8 letter char arrays. Not swapping correctly

Tags: c, arrays

I was asked to write a program that populated two 8 letter arrays using the getchar() function. then i was asked to swap the two arrays.

```
int main(void)
{
    char arr1[8];
    char arr2[8];
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    char hold[8];


    printf("Please enter 8 characters (Array 1):\t");

    while(counter < 8)
    {
        c = getchar();
        arr1[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    }

    counter=0;

    printf("Please enter 8 characters (Array 2):\t");   

    while(counter < 8) 
    {
        c = getchar();
        arr2[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    }


    counter=1;

    while (counter !=9) 
    {
        printf("\n%c",arr1[counter-1]);
        printf("\t%c",arr2[counter]);
        counter++;
    }

    counter=0;

    while (counter!=8)
    {
        hold[counter] = arr1[counter];
        arr1[counter] = arr2[counter];
        arr2[counter] = hold[counter];
        counter++;

    }
    printf("\n\n\n");

    counter=1;

    while (counter !=9) 
    {
        printf("\n%c",arr1[counter-1]);
        printf("\t%c",arr2[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong with the swapping of the arrays?

edit: i have realised that it might be my 2nd printf screwing up and not actually the swapping of the arrays.

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your program? Set a breakpoint, single-step, inspect variables, ... ?

Comment: And what is your output for an input? just saying *'it doesn't work'* isn't very helpful.

Comment: Please edit your question with the input/output and make it nicely formatted. Makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Your loops to print the arrays look suspicious. Why different indices for arr1 and arr2? Could it be that the first character in arr2 is a *newline* character from the previous input?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your swapping code, the way you print the arrays has some problems:

```
  while (counter !=9) 
  {
    printf("\n%c",arr1[counter-1]); // why -1?
    printf("\t%c",arr2[counter]); // will access array out of bounds (index 8)
    counter++;
  }
```

This is the corrected way:

```
  for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++)
  {
    printf("\n%c",arr1[counter]);
    printf("\t%c",arr2[counter]);
  }
```

Furthermore, you can simplify your swapping code by not using an array for `hold`:

```
char hold;
...

for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++)
{
    hold = arr1[counter];
    arr1[counter] = arr2[counter];
    arr2[counter] = hold;
}
```

As [aruisdante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3137499) suggested, `for` loops are much more appropiate for your use case than `while` loops

Comment: And in general, there's really no reason to use ``while`` here, ``for`` would be much safer.

Comment: when i tried to print out the arrays as simply arr1[counter] there is a \n underneath the q and no q in the secound array. same issue i have with the edit you just supplyed.

Comment: do you press enter in your input?

Comment: for the getchar(), yes i do. is there another way to do it? 
sorry if it seems stupid im just working off sheets that are not at all good

Comment: `getchar()` reads a character, `enter` is also a character. you can either not press enter when you input your characters, or you can ignore the enter by reading another character immediately

Answer (score 0):

Each of your array will take only 4 characters, since you are not flushing the stdin after reading the character. Also your swapping logic is wrong. You can use the following. Rather that correcting the swapping logic.

```
int main(void)
{
    char arr1[8 + 1] = {'\0'};
    char arr2[8 + 1] = {'\0'};
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Please enter 8 characters (Array 1):\t");

    while(counter < 8)
    {
        c = getchar();
        arr1[counter++] = c;
        __fpurge(stdin);
    }
    arr1[counter] = '\0';

    counter=0;
    printf("Please enter 8 characters (Array 2):\t");   

    while(counter < 8) 
    {
        c = getchar();
        arr2[counter++] = c;
        __fpurge(stdin);
    }

    arr2[counter] = '\0';
    puts(arr1);
    puts(arr2);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) // This will do the swapping.
    {
        c = arr1[i];
        arr1[i] = arr2[i];
        arr2[i] = c;
    }

    puts(arr1);
    puts(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

The `__fpurge(stdin);` is used to flush the stdin buffer each time you take a character. Otherwise getchar() will take newline (Enter key) also as one character, so in that case you can only read 4 characters. And you might consider terminating a char array with null character, for that purpose array size should be always, your desired size + 1.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys It was an accident, I don't know how to remove it. If you can do that please go ahead.